# Paste / NoQuote - Not Working as Expected

Tags: r

I have a Data Frame c1 as below:

```
str(c1)
#'data.frame':  2312 obs. of  6 variables:
# $ dt   : Date, format: "2014-04-01" "2014-04-01" "2014-04-01" ...
# $ base : Factor w/ 2 levels "AA","AB": 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 ...
# $ curr : Factor w/ 5 levels "BA","BB","BC",..: 2 3 5 1 2 3 4 2 3 5 ...
# $ trans: int  72 176 4365 234 144 352 16762 61 160 4276 ...
# $ amt  : num  2.18e+09 5.55e+09 9.99e+09 3.75e+08 4.37e+09 ...
# $ rate : num  1.11e-04 1.22e-02 1.26 3.94 5.65e+03 ...

d = "c1"
d
# [1] "c1"
```

Now then I use d instead of the actual data frame name it does not work correctly -

```
i <- sapply( c1, is.factor)
i
#   dt  base  curr trans   amt  rate 
#FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Correct!

```
i <- sapply( paste(d), is.factor)
i
#   c1 
#FALSE
```

Incorrect

```
i <- sapply( noquote(d), is.factor)
i
#   c1 
#FALSE
```

Incorrect

Is there a way to fix this?

Edit -

```
c1[i] <- lapply(c1[i], as.character)
```

Works

```
get(d)[i] <- lapply( get(d)[i], as.character)
```

Fails

```
for (j in 1:length(i)) { ifelse(is.factor(get(d)[j]),get(d)[i] <- as.character(get(d)[i])) }
```

Fails

Can get be used in every place or are there 3/4 ways to use get()

Thanks Again

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for

```
xy <- data.frame(a = runif(3), b = letters[1:3])
sapply(get("xy"), is.factor)
```

mind you this is bad practice. If you're making up variable names on-the-fly, you should consider using other objects, like a list, to store a data.frame(s).

Comment: Get Works - Yes.. But as of now i have only 1 data frames. So using a character rather than a list.. Thanks for the Help...

Comment: Can I use Get(x) in all places that I can use c1? So while c1[i] <- lapply(c1[i], as.character) Works --- get(d)[i] <- lapply(get(d)[i], as.character) Fails.. Is there a way to do this too?.. Apologies.. Asking Question in Comments

Comment: @myloginid I think you should show us what you're trying to achieve. In any case, I would suggest you store your data.frames in a list and use lapply to traverse the list.

Comment: I am starting to write a code that process around 10 data sets. In each of the datasets, i want to clean the data, make a model, score it and report the performance. I am ok to put data set names in Char Array or List. Either ways is fine. Unfortunately my base code that process 1 data set is only ready. I am trying to create the wrapper and facing issues in making the wrapper.

Comment: I have tried with - paste, noquote, get, .. if the command works in 1 place, it fails in the other... e.g. Get in the above Ifelse loop. It errors out while assigning the as.character(get(d)[i]) to get(d)[i] in this code -- get(d)[i] <- as.character(get(d)[i]))

Comment: If the process is the same for all data.frames, you're overcomplicating things. If you intend on processing each data.frame individually, I suggest you just work with actual data.frames and avoid calling the objects through characters using `get` etc.

Comment: Thanks.. But that will mean to manage multiple sets of codes.. and tomorrow if i have a new data frame added, i have to replicate the code. I am trying to avoid this...Also code manageability becomes an issue

Comment: Please join us in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75819/gmts or http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public so that we can pin-down what exactly you're trying to do, exchange in the comment section really isn't getting us nowhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85058/discussion-between-myloginid-and-roman-lustrik).

Answer (score -1):

This works for now. Although its exceptionally bad to make sense of.

```
.eval <- function(evaltext,envir=sys.frame()) {
  ## evaluate a string as R code
  eval(parse(text=evaltext), envir=envir)
}

.eval(paste( "i = sapply(",noquote(d),",is.factor)",sep=""))
.eval(paste( noquote(d),"[i] <- lapply(",noquote(d),"[i], as.character)",sep=""))
```

I am still looking for better alternatives. This is so bad that I cannot accept this as answer :-(

Thanks, Manish